# gazebo-1.4 with player example - errors

Tags: gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to get player to work with gazebo to control a pioneer robot.  I used the example provided with gazebo-1.4 in the `examples/player/position2d` folder.  Here are the problems I encountered:

1. The .world was in the old sdf format, so I tried using gzsdf to convert it.  gzsdf failed because the filename did not end with .sdf.  So after the renaming the world file, it worked.
2. Player was able to connect to gazebo and playerv opened its window, but when I tried to subscribe to position2d it gave the following error:

   GazeboDriver::GazeboDriver

   Gazebo Plugin driver creating 1 device

   ```
   6665.4.0 is  a position2d interface.
   ```

   Listening on ports: 6665

   accepted TCP client 0 on port 6665, fd 13

   libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format.cc:1059] Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while parsing protocol buffer. Strings must contain only UTF-8; use the 'bytes' type for raw bytes.

   libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Pose" because it is missing required fields: position, orientation

   closing TCP connection to client 0 on port 6665

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1627/gazebo-1.4-with-player-example---errors/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is a pull request that should fix this problem:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/352/update-player-position2d-interface-to-use

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-08**:
Hi,  I installed from mercurial today and ran the test again.  It works - I can control the robot using player, but I still get error messages such as:

libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Pose" because it is missing required fields: position, orientation
libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format.cc:1059] Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while parsing protocol buffer. Strings must contain only UTF-8; use the 'bytes'

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The Player interface in gazebo is out of date, you may have luck with the fixes in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1324/update-to-player-interfaces/diff

---

Originally posted by [rmattes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/62/rmattes/) with karma: 41 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1